# FirebaseInstallation class crashing in Android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Firebase Crashlytics have been reporting this crash on huge number of devices having Android 8 and Android 6 on playstore.
We are using dexguard in the app too.

Environment and Components I am using are as below.

Project build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0' // Crashlytics plugin
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin
```

App build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
```

These are the logs I am getting from Crashlytics.

```
???
com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy(:452)
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy(:331)
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy(:296)
at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$3.run(:2)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

It is not giving any hint so we can reproduce that crash on our devices but It is causing to a huge number of users.

Comment: Not sure why this was tagged under FCM (removed for now). Was there an update related to FCM prior to the crashes? Or like a push notif sent that _might've_ caused the crash?

Comment: We are not sure why this is causing as we only have traces from crashlytics. It can be related to a push causing that but still not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is already fixed by firebase in their latest release. I was using previous releases and now I have updated to the latest one. For more information visit this link.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2147

Answer (score 0):

My first guess it that you're using some incompatible versions of the Firebase SDKs, as there are many interdependencies under the hood.

These days, I'd recommend using the [Firebase BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) (bill of materials) to manage all the SDK versions. This allows you to specify a version only once (the version of the BoM), and then include all other SDKs without specifying a version.

To use the latest BoM and the SDKs in your question it'd look like:

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
```

If you want to see (or compare) what SDK versions are included in a certain BoM version, check this handy [BoM version comparator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#compare-bom-versions).